# Aromatisation of a ring which includes nitrogen

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

#### Question

> Complete the following reaction sequence:
>
> [image: 1‐methylidene‐2,3‐dihydroindene‐2‐carboxylic acid reaction scheme]

#### Answer

> [image: 1‐methylisoquinoline]

#### My solution

I was able to complete all the steps except for the last one. This is what I ended up with:

[image: 1‐methyl‐3,4‐dihydro‐2H‐isoquinoline‐1,3‐diol]

What I'm not getting is how the $\ce{-OH}$ groups are removed and the ring is aromatised. If anyone could provide me with a mechanism for the same, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Hint: An aldimine forms which reacts with the ketone to form the desired compound.

Comment: Does the aldimine form first and then attack the ketone( which means my final product may be incorrect)

Comment: That's would be rather easy part - simple elimination. Perhaps NH3 misled you about pH, as it's acid catalysed?

Comment: @Mithoron yes, i would think that was the problem.. I got it now, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be the mechanism I propose for the reaction:

> [image: Proposed mechanism]

I have taken the $\ce{pH}$ of the medium to be $4.5$. That should explain the protonation of the $\ce{-OH}$ groups.

Comment: Your final product is missing a methyl group. And I wouldn't draw both at the same time (but that's nitpicking). By the way, you should use the N lone pair to kick out the water next to it, then deprotonate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @orthocresol! I shall make the changes..

Comment: @orthocresol would it be correct now?

Comment: Yup, that’s pretty much what I’d have done, I think.

Comment: Also the last step should be removing of $\ce{H3O+}$ and not $\ce{H2O}$ but I think that was understood..

Comment: Well, two oxygens shouldn't be protonated at once, otherwise looks reasonable.

Comment: @Mithoron I would happily correct it, but what worries me is the continuous bumping of this question to the top of the front page...

Comment: Your q. and answer were edited only once - there are post that were edited *much* more, also as long as it was still a front page, that would be just moving it a bit. If it was a few dozen different questions edited, that would be an issue.